# PHP mail() funciton: replace sendmail using python or php script to support SMTP

Tags: php, python, email, smtp, sendmail

It seemed the default php `mail()` function is not easy to configure, and it just call the OS configured `sendmail` function to send an email.

Though installing an alternative `sendmail` do the trick, but configuring such a program also depends on the OS and the its self version, hard to control about.

So I think if there is a way to write a lightweight script of python or php, and make it as an executable, then replace the sendmail path in `php.ini`

```
; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = /some/script/pymail.py
```

And it supports setting any SMTP account on it.

Sending mail using python is not difficult, but is there a way to adapt the input parameters to the same or compatible with the `sendmail` command?

Is it possible or some exisiting work on this approach?

Comment: You really, really, REALLY need to look into [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Ditch sendmail and `mail()`

Comment: I'm maintaining an old site, and the mail() calls cannot be changed. I must configure the mail, but I'm trying to make a change. Is there way to write such a script of php using PHPMailer?

Comment: @Machavity Finally I found a repository works in GitHub, thank you.

Comment: @Machavity and I also worked out a simple python script myself, thank you.

Comment: @Machavity if you don't like my question, you may like my answer :D

Comment: Not my downvote. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Finally found some library to do the job.

https://github.com/chupikov/sendmail.py

Wiki: https://github.com/chupikov/sendmail.py/wiki

The final config term looks like below:

```
sendmail_path = /home/user/bin/sendmail.py/sendmail.py -c /home/user/bin/sendmail.py/php-apache2.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I also work out a simple script by myself:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import smtplib
from sys import stdin
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import email

s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.mydomain.com:465')
s.login('myaccount@mydomain.com','my_password')
mail = email.message_from_string(stdin.read())
s.sendmail(
    mail['from'] or 'myaccount@mydomain.com', 
    mail['to'] or mail['bcc'], 
    mail.as_string()
)
s.quit()
```

Just put the above script into `/usr/sbin/sendmail` or the actual place by `which sendmail`, make it executable `chmod +x /usr/sbin/sendmail` then test:

```
<?php
mail(
  "target@somemail.com",
  "Email Title",
  "Email Content",
  "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8;\n"
);
```

Simple enough!! And just requires python to be installed.

If it is nessesary (i.e. you want to sent through TLS port 587 or direct port 25), just change some the config referencing python [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html?highlight=smtplib#module-smtplib)

Comment: Great answer! Couldn't get it to work until I realized the permissions were insufficient. Also have to make sure that it can be executed **by the web server**. For example use: `sudo -u www-data bash` then try and execute sendmail.